# Override OnClick Event

Tags: c#, button, controls, overriding

I want to be able to execute something before the actual OnClick event is called upon a Button. I tried:

```
public class U_Button : Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuThinButton2
{
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Click");
        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

but the Messagebox is never shown. Any ideas why it doesn't work or how i can accomplish what i want to do? Because i want to avoid to write a check at the beginning of every OnClick event of a U_Button, so i thought i could somehow override it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the `OnClick` method even called? set a breakpoint, on `MessageBox.Show`

Comment: @Alex it is and i tested it with a messagebox before: `this.loadFromClipboard_Button.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.loadFromClipboard_Button_Click);`

Comment: Just to be clear: Registering an event handler, and overriding an event invocator are different things. Are you sure you use the U_Botton in your UI?

Comment: @Alex 100% sure

Comment: To recap: `MessageBox.Show("Click");` line gets called, but no `MessageBox` is shown? try wrapping the call to `.Show(..)` in a `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke()`

Comment: @Alex no no, I showed a messagebox in the actual loadFromClipboard_Button_Click method, it doesnt enter the override click method! (MessageBoxes work fine!)

Comment: This is definitely something that would work well in a [winforms] app.  This Bufinu framework, hmm, I'm seeing SO users have lots of wonky problems with it.  If you want to use it then you need to depend on their support services and, probably, not live too far away from Kenia.  Tool vendors that depend on a login wall to access their KB articles usually have something to hide.